# acquiring POST from submit button through objects in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I'm using objects to acquire a form (which contains a submit button) from another page. I can't seem to figure out how to get the POSTED info from that submit button and I'm thinking I may need ajax.

So for example

```
Page 1  calls to page1processing for a form

$getform = new page1processing;
$getform->form1($arbitraryVariable);
```

page 1 processing contains the form

```
Class page1processing{

  function form1($arbitraryVariables){
    echo <form name=.....>
    echo 'pretend this is info for some text boxes and junk';
    echo '<input type="submit" name ="submitButton"/>';
    }
   if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
       .....
    }
```

So, I guess what I'm asking is where exactly am I supposed to place the if statement to check if "submitButton" has been pressed? Should it be on page1 or page1processing? I've some time fumbling through a bunch of code and can't figure out whether it's an error with my code, or my procedure of checking for posted info.

The reason why I have the form on the other page is just to keep page1 clutter free. I find it easier to drop an object inside HTML than a huge block of code.

Comment: dude, i'd recommend you revisit the concepts of OOP and look at using classes properly before moving forwards with what you are currently doing

Comment: there's nothing special about forms that make them incomparable with OOP

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ajax/jquery solution.   You can use a class or ID, live or delegate.

```
        $("#submitButton").live('submit', function(e) {

                //CODE HERE
        });
```